# How do I switch my application workspace in neutrinos-platform?

Tags: neutrinos-platform

I am building a neutrinos application using neutrinos platform. The workspace folder is set to c:\users\\neutrinos-studio. I would like to change this folder to someother location. How do I do the same?

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution worked. !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the button at the top right corner as shown in the image below to switch work-space. Once clicked a window opens up from where you can select any work-space of your choosing.

Hope this helps!

[image: Workspace Switch Button Location]